# Ubuntu and other software completely unable to detect a usb drive

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, corruption

I was attempting to flash a USB drive so that I could install Windows on a different HDD, but in the process, it became completely unreadable.

So now whenever I try using it it does not appear in any programs, nor terminal, and i've tried on different computers, no luck.

I Want to know if there's some kind of software for this or something else I can do; Because if there is I can't find it.

Comment: If the device doesn't show up with `lsusb` then it's dead.

Comment: I Also forgot to add that when I plug in the usb it makes a notification sound as usual. This only happens for usb drives and nothing else.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add what you forgot, not comments. Also post exactly what shows and doesn't with the commands, namely the one mentioned above. Furthermore, you CAN'T currently flash a ny Microsoft ISO using the normal tools in Linux. You can however use Ventoy.